# CRON expression, nearest Friday to your day

Tags: cron

I need a complex cron expression, wonder can i do it and how.
I need to CRON work like this:

1. Every 20th day of the every month if it's not Sunday or Saturday
2. If it's Saturday, then 19th day of the month
3. If it's Sunday, then 18th day of the month

Is it possible? How?

I found 'nearest weekday to your day'.
Is there 'nearest friday to your day' in CRON?